# The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'. show status

Tags: mysql, flutter, dart

I retrieve the flags from the database. I store the status as a number, but I want it to show as text, so I create a getStatusText() method to convert the number to text. Then pull the value to show **getStatusText(problem.status.toString())**  but got error **The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'.** How do I fix it to show the status normally?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evi2h.png)

```
class _view_problemState extends State<view_problem> {
  TextEditingController _searchController = TextEditingController();

  List<problemModel> problemlist = [];
  List<problemModel> originalList = [];
  StreamController _streamController = StreamController();
  Future getAllProblem() async {
    problemlist = await problemcontrollers().getProblem();
    originalList = problemlist;
    _streamController.sink.add(problemlist);
  }

  String getStatusText(int statusCode) {
    switch (statusCode) {
      case 0:
        return 'Unauthorized';
      case 1:
        return 'Authorized';
      case 2:
        return 'Initial';
      default:
        return 'UnRecognised';
    }
  }

   Expanded(
              child: StreamBuilder(
                stream: _streamController.stream,
                builder: (context, snapshots) {
                 if (snapshots.hasData) {
                   return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: problemlist.length,
                        itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                          problemModel problem = problemlist[index];
                          return Card(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            child: ListTile(
                              leading: CircleAvatar(
                                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                  'http://192.168.1.6/skc/Problem_image/${problem.image}',
                                ),
                              ),
                              subtitle: Text(
                                getStatusText(problem.status.toString()),
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 17),
                             ),
                           ),
                         );
                      }));
```

Comment: ```getStatusText(int statusCode)``` vs. ```getStatusText(problem.status.toString())```.  ```problem.status.toString()``` is a string.   ```getStatusText()'s``` parameter requires an ```int```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
getStatusText(problem.status.toString())
```

I think you dont need to convert problem.status to String. It has to be an integer.

```
getStatusText(int.parse(problem.status))
```

This should fix your problem.